# How to display a cli mercurial opération using zenity

Tags: bash, mercurial, zenity

I'm trying to display the advancement of a mercurial pull using zenity.

The command I want to display is the following `hg pull -ufb develop`, using `zenity --no-cancel --progress --auto-close --auto-kill --title="Mercurial"`

Thank for your help.

Edit 1 :

Here is a sample of an hg pull :

```
searching for changes
adding changesets
adding manifests
adding file changes
files [============>                                          ]  3281/13321 23s
```

I would like to display `the number of object already downloaded` (here, 3281) `/ objects to download` (here, 13321), and the estimated time to completion (here, 23s), with the progress bar following the amount of object already downloaded (3281/13321*100).

The objective is to build an auto-updater for a small game project, in order to make the game automatically download the latest ressources from our mercurial repository (and showing a nice little gtk window instead of an ugly bash window).

Comment: Is it not working? How is it not working? What does the output from `hg pull` look like exactly?

Comment: Edited (Edit 1) with a sample, and some explanation of why I'm trying to do this.

Comment: Given the documentation on `--progress` you'll need to filter the output from `hg` to fit the format expected by `zenity` as input. Is how to do that the question? Have you looked at the documentation for `--progress` and understand how its input works? Have you tried to write the "conversion" code?